# How to register the device via SOAP?

Tags: c#, soap, stream, dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm-online

I'm executing the following code in order to register a randomized user name and a password for login using live id.

```
String regUrl = "https://login.live.com/ppsecure/DeviceAddCredential.srf";
WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(regUrl);
request.ContentType = "application/soap+xml; charset=UTF-8";
request.Method = "POST";
request.Timeout = 60000;

StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(request.GetRequestStream());
String contents = reader.ReadToEnd();
```

I'm following the code in [this article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg328147.aspx) and it's not going quick nor easy. I get the error telling me that *stream was not readable*.

What am I missing and what can be done about it?

Answer (score 3):

You're trying to read from a request stream, when you should be writing to it. The *response* stream contains the server's reply.